# Can you preload files with Plex

Tags: streaming, plex

I am running Plex Server on my desktop, and I stream to my Windows Phone (WP 8.1) and Surface Pro 3 (W8.1) with it. However, it often happens that I am leaving my home for a bit to somewhere where there's no internet connection whatsoever. My question therefore is, can I "preload" files (movies or music) with Plex.

What I mean by this is that the movie is streamed while I am at home, and temporarily saved on the storage of the device and after playing it back, it is removed from the device. Is there such functionality available for Plex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The good:**

Yes it is possible, you can [sync media to a device](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/201053678-Sync-Media-to-a-Device). Additionally Plex Sync supports the [Windows Phone client](http://www.wpcentral.com/plex-windows-phone-8-updated-adds-plex-sync-mix). As far as I know they don't have any options to automatically delete the content from your device, but manually deleting it as it fills up isn't too hard.

**The bad:**

The feature requires [Plex Pass](https://plex.tv/subscription/about), so either you have to pay a reoccurring fee or pay a lump sum upfront.